# Jobs removed from registry when Spring XD is killed

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I'm running Spring XD as single-node for my Sandbox environment with a MySQL DB for the batch tables. If I kill -15 the Spring XD process, then all the current definitions for my jobs and streams are lost (in the case of the jobs, the XD_JOB_REGISTRY is apparently deleted). Consequently, if I start up Spring XD again, I have lost all the previous jobs and streams definitions.

I would like to know whether this is intentional in Spring XD, or maybe due to the fact that I run in single-node mode? Or is it a bug?

EDITED TO ADD THE GIST OF SERVERS.YML:

https://gist.github.com/emedina/486b52f11bc146203534

Comment: If you could post your servers.yml, that would help.

Comment: Sure, here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/emedina/486b52f11bc146203534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job and stream definitions are stored in Zookeeper while the stats for any executed jobs are stored in the database. The single-node server uses an embedded Zookeeper instance by default and that's my guess why your definitions are gone when restarting. Try setting up a separate Zookeeper instance with a permanent data location.

Comment: However, that brings up another question: what if the Zookeeper is killed or dies for whatever reason? Can its info be persisted to be durable?